# Is a select after casting a data frame to dataset optimized?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, catalyst-optimizer

I have the following scenario:

```
 case class A(name:String,age:Int)
 val df = List(A("s",2)).toDF
 df.write.parquet("filePath")
 val result = spark.read.parquet("filePath").as[A].select("age")
```

Is the above optimized to select only `age` ? Upon seeing `result.explain` I see the following

```
'Project [unresolvedalias('age, None)]
+- Relation[name#48,age#49] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
age: int
Project [age#49]
+- Relation[name#48,age#49] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [age#49]
+- Relation[name#48,age#49] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan parquet [age#49] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location:    InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Volumes/Unix/workplace/Reconciliation/src/TFSReconciliationCore/~/Downloa..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<age:int>
```

It seems only `age` is read. But then what purpose does `as` serve ? Am I correct in reading the physical plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are reading it right. Parquet file has two columns - `name` and `age`:

```
 Relation[name#48,age#49] parquet
```

But in fact, only `age` is going to be read:

```
 Project [age#49]
```

> But then what purpose does as serve?

For optimizations, like the one above, Spark needs to create an internal schema.

In some cases, like `parquet` files, we have a footer that contains metadata with schema, though by default Spark has to read all footers to merge, possibly,  different schemas.
In others (`csv`, `json`, etc), if a user doesn't provide a schema, Spark needs to scan the data and create it.

We also need some generic container which will give us access to the values, and we have one it is called `Row`.

> [Row](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Row.html) is a generic row object with an ordered collection of fields
>   that can be accessed by an ordinal / an index (aka generic access by
>   ordinal), a name (aka native primitive access) or using Scala's
>   pattern matching.

In your example, it is perfectly fine to write the following code:

```
spark.read.parquet("filePath").select("age")
```

Read method returns `Dataframe`, which in fact just a [`Dataset of Rows`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c26379b446e90b3104ebe36f288be483f613a652/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/package.scala#L46).
When we use `as` we are converting `Dataset[Row]` to `Dataset[A]` where `A` could be almost any case-class.

In my point of view, it makes code cleaner and more readable. It doesn't make much difference when working in SQL-like approach, but when we need to add map/flatMap or custom aggregations into the mix the code will become more understandable.